# Custom URL routing including identifier/controller/method

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I'm trying to create a bug tracking software with multiple projects support.

To achieve that I'd like to use a URL like this:

```
http://example.com/project/default_project/tickets/view/123
```

`project` is the Project-Controller

`default_project` is in this case the project identifier.

`tickets` is the controller

`view` is the method in the tickets-controller

`123` is the ID of the ticket passed to `view`

How do I create such a routing?

My controller would look like this:

```
class Tickets extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        // load all tickets WHERE project_identifier = $this->uri->segment(1)
    }
    public function view($id) {
        // load ticket WHERE project_identifier = $this->uri->segment(n)
        // AND ticket_id = $id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding this line to routes.php in the config folder:

```
$route['project/(:any)/ticket/(:num)'] = 'tickets/view/$1/$2';
```